# Laravel Command/Controller Shared logic

Tags: php, laravel, controller, command, logic

Is there a general place that I could put logic that can be shared between the controllers and commands in Laravel. I have functionality that will most often times be run from command line via stored procedure, but also need the same (or a subset) of the functionality via web.

Can I use controller logic within the command? Or call the command from the controller/route?

Or should I just build my own classes and include them as needed in both?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just create a app/libraries folder. In that create a custom_helpers.php file and autoload it. Store your methods that your going to be using often there. Think of it like the helper class provided by laravel by default.